# How can I use variables defined in javascript under functions in other functions. below is my exact Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    $(".demo").append("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
}
var gettingJSON = function() {

    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "APPID=4a74787aeb02dcb53dcc8c15e29bdfa1", function(json) {
        $(".para").append(JSON.stringify(json));
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getLocation();
    gettingJSON();
});
```

Above is my Code I'm getting the following error

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: lat is not defined ReferenceError: lat is not defined
    at gettingJSON (file:///G:/WebDev/WeatherAPI/js/main.js:19:73)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///G:/WebDev/WeatherAPI/js/main.js:26:1)
    at j (file:///G:/WebDev/WeatherAPI/js/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (file:///G:/WebDev/WeatherAPI/js/jquery.min.js:2:30262) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: lat is not defined
    at gettingJSON (main.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:26)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
gettingJSON @ main.js:19
(anonymous) @ main.js:26
j @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
```

The Code is not Working. I'm trying to get use lat and lon from the showPosition Fucntion, but it saying that lat and lon are not defined.
I had made lat and lon global variables by not using var keyword.
but they are not working. please anyone help me.

Comment: `lat` and `lon` become available in the **global** scope only after you call `showPosition()`.  Nowhere in your code are you calling `showPosition()`.

Comment: Thats not how you define global variables in JavaScript. If you want variables accessible to all functions, define them outside of functions like you did with `x`. You still need to use `var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the issue-

Your getLocation() function doesn't populate lat and lon fast enough,
So when gettingJSON() is called lat and lon don't exist yet.

I've tested it with a 5 sec wait here-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getLocation();  
    gettingJSON();
    //checking lon and lat immediatelly
    console.log("lon:"+lon+ "lat:"+ lat);
    //setting a 5 sec timeout, and checking the lon and lat value again
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log('waiting');
        console.log("lon:"+lon+ "lat:"+ lat);
        }, 5000); 
});
```

console log:

```
lon: undefined lat: undefined
after wait:
lon: 34.99041030000001 lat: 32.7888574
```

This is probably because the user doesn't allow the location check fast enough.

Maybe try changing the code like this:

```
function showPosition(position) {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  $(".demo").append("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
  gettingJSON(); //calling gettingJSON here assures that you already have the coordinates
}
```

Comment: very nice guess @Shtut but brother my function getLocation and showPosition pass the values of coordinates to the variables. defining global empty variables outside the function will not help as they will remain empty forever. because there global value is not being changed by the getLocation Function. anyone else can please answer me or please pass on to anyone else I'm a little eager to get the job done. thanks for answer well.

Comment: @Syed Sadiq ali ,  I see what you mean. Have you considered that maybe the getLocation function takes a while to get the parameters, and that gettingJSON just happens too fast afterwards (before parameters were filled?)

maybe try adding a sleep of 10 sec to see if you still don't get values

Comment: no. @Shtut . appreciate you friend, for quick and nice responses but I had tried. and it not working and I'm so dumb in javascript or say every language this time. that I can't understand what's happening. Surely I'll tell you the problem and finded solution. thanks again.

Comment: @Syed Sadiq ali I think I figured out your issue - updated the answer  :)

Comment: actually this is not correct answer sorry. the correct answer is given by @dev8080 that I have to take arguments of the function as lat and lon so that they can be passed to the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access those variables I'd recommend returning them from the function. Or you could do the same thing using class objects.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for you to access a variable in all functions, they should have a global scope. This means that they are declared outside the functions.

Your `lat` and `lon` function are declared locally inside the `showPosition(position)`. This means that they can only be accessed by the `showPosition(position)` function and not the `gettingJSON()` function.

It should work if you declare `var lat=position.coords.latitude;` and `lon=position.coords.longitude;` outside and before the `showPosition(position)` function.

If you are working on freecodecamp, here is a link where global and local variable scope are explained.
[FreeCodeCamp: Global Scope](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/global-scope-and-functions), [FreeCodeCamp: Local Scope](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/local-scope-and-functions), [FreeCodeCamp: Global vs Local Scope](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/global-vs-local-scope-in-functions)

In addition, you did not call the `showPosition(position)` function remember to do this after adjusting your variable declaration as indicated by one of the comments

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm totally beginner AF. so don't think it's childish. but I'm not understanding the navigator.geoLocation Function, it uses two Functions, one is success and other is error function. the first function uses position attribute. if i define as you sad the lat and long variables. then it says position is not defined, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined. If I declare barely var position outside. I'm complete beginner please explain. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put it all into a self-executing function and then declare your variables at the beginning. That way, they're not GLOBAL (you generally don't want to make variables GLOBAL) but they're available to everything in your code:

```
(function($){
  var lat, lon, x;

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    $(".demo").append("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
      "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
  }

  var gettingJSON = function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "APPID=4a74787aeb02dcb53dcc8c15e29bdfa1", function(json) {
      $(".para").append(JSON.stringify(json));
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    x = document.getElementById("demo");
    getLocation();
    gettingJSON();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you do get the values of lat, long you could consider changing the structure of your program, and call gettingJSON  **inside** showPosition:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    $(".demo").append("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);

    //call gettingJson here, pass it lat, lon values...sure to work if lat,lon is in fact gettting populated.
    gettingJSON(lat, lon);

}
var gettingJSON = function(lat, lon) {

$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "APPID=4a74787aeb02dcb53dcc8c15e29bdfa1", function(json) {
    $(".para").append(JSON.stringify(json));
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getLocation();
});
```